# How to save ESXI 4.0 configuration without reboot

Tags: vmware-esxi

HI,everyone

Recently, I set the VM start with the ESXI at the "Virtual Machine Startup/Shutdown" , and move up the VM at the "Startup Order" until the VM startup changed to Enabled.

Once ,the ESXI server was crashed with no power. Late, I Manual start the ESXI server . but when I login the ESXI with vsphere, I found the VM without startup .

The same situation，when after I set the VM startup . then I reboot the ESXI ,the VM is startup.

So, I want to have a way that save the VM startup configuration without reboot ESXI .

sorry ， my english is very poor , please forgive !

Comment: Hi bruce, welcome to serverfault.com. This works different than most forums and I think you found out a bit yourself.
Answers are meant as answers, not as posts in a thread. So you should remove your "answer" below.
If the answer provided by Massimo works fine, then you should "accept" that answer: it will increase your answer acceptance percentage, and also gives Massimo some credits for posting a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to save, "Virtual Machine Startup/Shutdown" is immediately applied as soon as you configure it, and doesn't need a server reboot in order to work.

The problem here is that your ESXi host didn't shut down properly, so it was unable to save its configuration; but, as long as the system is shut down or rebooted cleanly, you don't usally have to do anything at all in order to make your configuration changes permanent.

---

### Update:

If you really want to force ESX to save its configuration, this should help:

```
/usr/sbin/esxcfg-boot -r
```

It's the command that gets executed at ESX shutdown/reboot to save the system configuration, so it *should* do what you're looking for.

But you're running ESXi, so you don't have access to the Service Console... it can be obtained (see [here](http://vmwaretips.com/wp/2008/10/20/access-the-esxi-service-console/)), but I don't know if that command even *exists* in ESXi.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,Massimo

When i add new VM, I do not want to reboot ESXI, because I do not want to stop the vms previos on the ESXI. SO, I want a way to save configuration when the ESXI host didn't shut down properly.

Thanks very much , I know it is difficult to resolve!